# Adding control with events programmatically inside a loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0

I am having trouble adding a control programmatically in a `Panel` where the control has an event inside a loop. Here's my code:

```
pnlAccompanies.Controls.Clear();

foreach (var accompany in this.RetrieveAccompanyList())
{
    var btnRemoveAccompany = new LinkButton();
    btnRemoveAccompany.CommandArgument = accompany.AccompanyID.ToString();
    btnRemoveAccompany.CssClass = "close";
    btnRemoveAccompany.Controls.Add(new Literal() { Text = "&times;" });
    btnRemoveAccompany.Click += this.btnRemoveAccompany_Click;
    smGTPForm.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(btnRemoveAccompany);

    pnlAccompanies.Controls.Add(btnRemoveAccompany);
}
```

And here's my code of the event:

```
protected void btnRemoveAccompany_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var accompanyID = ((LinkButton)sender).CommandArgument.Parser<int>();
    var accompanies = this.RetrieveAccompanyList();
    if (accompanies.Exists(o => o.AccompanyID == accompanyID))
    {
        accompanies.RemoveAll(o => o.AccompanyID == accompanyID);
        HttpContext.Current.Session["gtpd_accompany01"] = accompanies;
        this.PopulateAccompanyList();
    }
}
```

When I have 2 or more value in the `accompanies`, the return of the `((LinkButton)sender).CommandArgument` **is always the last one in the loop**, even though I specifically put a different value in each iteration in the `((LinkButton)sender).CommandArgument`. Why is it like this?

My code is in C# 4.0, ASP.NET, build in VS2010 Pro.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: how and where is this defined..? `RetrieveAccompanyList` can you do a .Sort on the `RetrieveAccompanyList`?

Comment: `RetrieveAccompanyList` is just getting the value of my `"gtpd_accompany01"` session. I contains a `List<Accompany>` so I guess it was chronologically sorted. I debug my program and saw that the value inserted in the  `btnRemoveAccompany.CommandArgument` is different in each iteration, but when the event access it, it is always the last value of the list.

Comment: you need to show all relevant code.. I would need to see how `RetrieveAccompanyList` is defines also if you are holding values in a List<Accompany> can you sort on that after the list is loaded

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but a suggestion: `List<T>.RemoveAll()` returns the number of items that were removed, so you don't need the call to `Exists`.  Instead, use `if (accompanies.RemoveAll(o => o.AccompanyID == accompanyID) != 0) { HttpContext.Current.Session["gtpd_accompany01"] = accompanies; this.PopulateAccompanyList(); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not assigned the ID value for btnRemoveAccompany,so when you click on this button ,event doesn't know which control raised this event,as all the controls have same attributes.try adding ID value for all the Controls.